# Is there anyway to tell if a function has a state in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, functional-programming, closures

```
a = function() {
    if(this.n === undefined) {
        this.n = 0;
    }
    this.n += 1;
    return(this.b);
}
b = function() {
    return(5);
}
```

In this case `a` would stateful, and `b` would be stateless. Is it possible to create in javascript a function `hasSate(f)`, which returns `true` if it has state like in `a`, and returns `false` if it doesn't have a state like `b`? If so, how would you do this?

Comment: A better question is why does something like that need to be dynamic?  As a developer of your logic, you should be aware of what your methods do.

Comment: return is not a method.

Comment: No, that is not possible, because state is a side effect. It is not part of the language. You could test whether a function is non-idempotent due to being stateful (by calling it twice with the same argument). However, this is a bad idea, because it would alter this very state. And not every stateful function is non-idempotent.

Comment: @epascarello This is valid JavaScript though; read it this way `return (this.b);` It _can_ be useful if you want to evaluate code and provide a return value in the same line e.g. `return (console.log('foo'), 5);` returns `5` and has logged `'foo'` too. Why you would want to do it this way is another story but the point is that it is valid code. And I don't think we can assume that OP didn't know that `return` was a statement rather than a method.

Comment: @customcommander I know reason why you would do it, but there is no reason to do it in the code above. I have been telling people for the last 20+ years to drop the () with return.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance of the function and check if there are propertyNames associated with that new instance with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` function.

```js
let a = function() {
    if(this.n === undefined) {
        this.n = 0;
    }
    this.n += 1;
    return b();
}
let b = function() {
    return 5;
}


function hasState(fn) {
  let x = new fn();
  if(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(x).length > 0) {
     return true;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(hasState(a))
console.log(hasState(b));
```